# Problema al iterar una linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteradores

Quiero iterar dentro de una linked list hasta encontrar el valor que ingresa el usuario, cuando lo haga regresar `True` para así validar el while, sin embargo parece ser que solo regresa `True` al dato del primer nodo.

```
class nodo:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def listprint(self):
        imprimirlote = self.head
        while imprimirlote is not None:
            print (imprimirlote.data)
            imprimirlote = imprimirlote.next
    # Function to add newnode
    def AtEnd(self, newdata):
        NewNode = nodo(newdata)
        if self.head is None:
            self.head = NewNode
            return
        laste = self.head
        while(laste.next):
            laste = laste.next
        laste.next=NewNode
    def RemoveNode(self, RemoveItem):

        headval = self.head

        if (headval is not None):
            if (headval.data == RemoveItem):
                self.head = headval.next
                headval = None
                return

        while (headval is not None):
            if headval.data == RemoveItem:
                break
            prev = headval
            headval = headval.next

        if (headval == None):
            return

        prev.next = headval.next

        headval = None
    def Iretare(self, Item):
        headval= self.head
        
        if (headval is not None):
            if (headval.data==Item):
                self.head=headval.next
                return True
        while (headval is not None):
            if headval.data == Item:
                break
            prev = headval
            headval = headval.next        
        if (headval == None):
            return False

        prev.next = headval.next
        headval=None
                
        
availableparking=Linked_list()
unavailableparking=Linked_list()
availableparking.AtEnd("A17")
availableparking.AtEnd("A4")
availableparking.listprint()
a=0
b=availableparking.Iretare(a)
while not b:
   a=input("") 

   b=availableparking.Iretare(a)
```

Comment: Implementar una lista enlazada en Python ... LOL!

Comment: Lo se, es un trabajo de estructura de datos, y debo simular una linked list en este lenguaje.

Comment: ¿Por qué `Iretare`? La palabra es "iterate" o "iterar".

Comment: Perdon, escribí mal, estoy un poco fastidiado trabjanado en esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo único que te falta es un `return` al final de la función `Iretate`:

```
    prev.next = headval.next
    headval = None
    # OJO: Falta un return
    return True
```

Modifique la parte en que pruebas la función:

```
b = None
while not b:
    a = input("lugar? ")
    b = availableparking.Iretare(a)
    if b:
        print("Desocupado")
    else:
        print("Ocupado")
```

**Demo**

```
A17
A4
lugar? A5
Ocupado
lugar? A4
Desocupado
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ¡eres grande!

Answer (score 1):

El error que tenías ya te lo indicó muy correctamente Candid Moe. Sin embargo, me gustaría aportar ciertas cosas a tu situación que vienen muy al caso y que te permitirá tener una implementación verdaderamente *pythonic*, (así sea para fines académicos).

En primer lugar, tenemos que hablar un poco acerca de un Patrón de Diseño llamado [Iterator](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterador_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)). La intención de este patrón es, para no entrar en demasiados detalles, separar las colecciones (en tu caso la Linked List) de los comportamientos relacionados a su recorrido (o iteración).

Python es un lenguaje que adopta casi totalmente este Patrón de Diseño. Es, de hecho, en mi opinión, el Patrón de la [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) que más fácil y naturalmente se implementa en el lenguaje.

En ese sentido, Python provee el [Iterator Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), el cual nos arma de una poderosa herramienta para definir el comportamiento que queramos que se aplique al momento de iterar una colección. Para esto debemos, sencillamente, contar con lo siguiente:

- Una clase que sea nuestro container, o colección, y que defina un método `__iter__()`, el cual debe devolver una instancia de...
- ... una clase que sea nuestro iterador. Dentro de esta clase debemos definir, a su vez, un método `__iter__` que devuelva el mismo objeto iterador, y un método `__next__` que devuelva el siguiente elemento (en tu caso: nodo) de la iteración.

Bien, ya con este trasfondo teórico podemos codificar una linked list en Python que se adapte al Iterator Pattern, mediante el aprovechamiento del Iterator Protocol. Luciría así:

**Definición de los nodos:**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next_node=None):
        self.next_node = next_node
        self.data = data
```

**Definición del iterador:**

```
class LinkedListIterator:
    def __init__(self, linked_list):
        self.linked_list = linked_list
        self.current_node = self.linked_list.head    # <---- Los iteradores son stateful ("recuerdan")

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current_node is None:
            raise StopIteration    # <---- Es nuestro deber levantar esta excepción cuando ya no hayan elementos que iterar
        node, self.current_node = self.current_node, self.current_node.next_node
        return node
```

**Definición de la linked list:**

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head):
        self.head = head

    def append(self, new_node):
        for node in self:    # <--- Python llamará automáticamente el iterador de esta clase...
            if node.next_node is None:
                node.next_node = new_node

    def __iter__(self):    # <---- ... el cual es devuelto acá.
        return LinkedListIterator(self)
```

Gracias a esto, podemos aprovechar los mecanismos internos del lenguaje para escribir cosas como:

```
>>> linked_list = LinkedList(Node('a'))
>>> linked_list.append(Node('b'))
>>> linked_list.append(Node('c'))

>>> for node in linked_list:
    print(node.data)

a
b
c
```

Así, para seguir haciendo uso de los [métodos mágicos](https://medium.com/fintechexplained/advanced-python-what-are-magic-methods-d21891cf9a08), protocolos y mecanismos, en lugar de que tengas ese método `listprint()`, puedes tener:

```
class LinkedList:
    # ...
    # Todo lo demás que ya habíamos escrito
    # ...

    def __str__(self):
        list_content = ', '.join(str(node.data) for node in self)
        return f'[{list_content}]'
```

De manera tal que al hacer:

```
print(linked_list)
```

Se nos devuelva:

```
[a, b, c]
```

Incluso, puedes hasta implementar el método `__getitem__` para hacer que tu lista sea subscriptable, o el método `__len__` para que se te devuelva la longitud de la lista... Pero creo que ya hasta acá es suficiente y puedes seguir jugando por ti mismo con esto, para lograr los demás comportamientos que desees ;)